# LeetCode 69 - Why int(2.0) equals 1?

Tags: python-3.x, int

My code is as following：

```
import math
class Solution(object):
    def mySqrt(self, x):
        """
        :type x: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if x == 0: return 0

        res = pow(math.e, 0.5 * math.log(x))
        print(res)

        return int(res)
```

This is based on the idea that [image]

When the test case is `4`, it's expected to output `2` but it gives `1` back.

I check the value of `res` which is `2.0`.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: Please leave out the unnecessary `Solution` class that isn't required for reproducing your problem. You should always create a [mcve]

Comment: But anyway, the *actual* value of res is *not exactly 2.0*, (floating point math is imprecise) it is a little under it, I'm getting something like (1.9999999999999998) so `int` will give you `1`

Comment: And note, if you are going to use the `math` module to solve this, you might as well just use `math.sqrt`

Comment: you need infinite precision of `e`, `ln` and `pow` operations to get the exact 2.0 output which is impossible to achieve. You'll always get an approximate of the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you `print(repr(res))` you will see that `res = 1.9999999999999998` the `int` of that is indeed `1`.

you could `return ruound(res)` (there is the [doc of `round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round)) if that suits your use-case.

if your are interested in [integer square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) only this wikipedia article may be interesting for you.

Comment: Thx! This help me a lot in understanding `int` in `python`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
     public int mySqrt(int x) {
          long i = 0;
          long j = x;
          int mid = 0;
          if (x == 0) {
              return 0;
          }
          if (x == 1) {
              return 1;
          }
          while (i <= j) {
              mid = (int)(i + j)/2;
              if (x/mid == mid) {
                  return (int)mid;
              } else if (x/mid > mid) {
                  i = mid + 1;
              } else if (x/mid < mid) {
                  j = mid - 1;
              }
          }
          return (int)j;
          }

  }
```

Try this code using Java format at Leetcode you will pass...